# About the construction of the associated complex vector bundle of an orbifold one

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, orbifolds

My question has to do with the general construction that associates to each complex orbifold vector bundle $\mathscr E\rightarrow\mathscr X$ over an orbifold Riemann surface, a complex vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$ over the underlying surface. Here we are using that, for each singular point $x_i\in X$ with order $n_i$, there exists an orbifold chart of the form $(\mathbb D^2,\mathbb Z_{n_i},\varphi_i\circ\psi_i)$, where $\varphi_i:\mathbb D^2\rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism over $D_i$, an open subset containing $x_i$, and $\psi_i:\mathbb D^2\rightarrow\mathbb D^2$ is such that
$$\psi_i(z)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }z=0,\\
z^{n_i}/|z|^{n_i-1}&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
In many references (for instance in Chen-Ruan's article about orbifold cohomology, Furuta-Steer's or Nasatyr-Steer's article about Yang-Mills-Higgs equations over orbifold Riemann surfaces, in the case of line bundles) it is asserted that the trivialization of $\mathscr E|_{D_i\setminus\{x_i\}}$ induced by the orbifold chart of $x_i$ induces an ordinary trivialization, that is, a diffeomorphism between $\mathscr E|_{D_i\setminus\{x_i\}}$ and $D_i\setminus\{x_i\}\times\mathbb C^n$ determined by the $\mathbb Z_{m_i}$-invariant map
$$\Psi_i:(\mathbb D^2\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb C^n\rightarrow(\mathbb D^2\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb C^n,\quad(z,v_1,\dots,v_n)\mapsto(z^{n_i}/|z|^{n_i-1},z^{-k_{i,1}}v_1,\dots,z^{-k_{i,n}}v_n),$$
where $0\leq k_{i,1},\dots,k_{i,n}<n_i$ are the orders of the isotropy representation $\rho_i:\mathbb Z_{n_i}\rightarrow\text{GL}(\mathbb C^n)$. I see how this stablishes a trivialization of the aforementioned bundle, however, I don't understand how can one possibly extend this map to determine a trivialization over the whole $D_i$, and hence get an ordinary complex vector bundle over $X$, after repeating the process for each singular point of $\mathscr X$. This doesn't make much sense to me, because approaching to 0 just makes the whole of $\mathbb C^n$ collapse.

How can we construct such a vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$ then?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think you first have to construct the sheaf of holomorphic sections of the vector bundle you want to construct on $X$. Afterwards, you show that the constructed sheaf is locally free and comes from a vector bundle on $X$. On a side note, I'm a little bit puzzled by your nonholomorphic maps $\psi_i$...

Comment: Well, that construction I understand correctly, but it only associated a vector bundle in case it is holomorphic, not differentiable with complex fibers, which supposedly this general construction tells us about.